# Silverlight: Unable to install xap with sllauncher.exe

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm trying to install my Silverlight OOB application via the sllauncher.exe.

The problem is, when I'm creating a new Silverlight project and try to install the xap, the shortcuts are generated and everythings fine.
When I'm using my current Silverlight project and try to install it, no shortcuts are generated, no files copied, and the sllauncher.exe doesn't throw any error message.

I checked all of the properties between the two projects and they are the same. I tried to install the application on another computer, but it still doesn't get installed.
The folder for the application in the AppData is created, but there aren't any files in it.

The fun fact is, that it was working in the past, but over the time I must have changed something, which screwed up the installation process, but I really don't know what. Also because the sllauncher.exe doesn't throw any error messages, I'm kinda lost what's causing this.

Does anyone has any idea?